# ASROCK Q1900B-ITX won't start

Tags: motherboard, power

I have a ASROCK Q1900B-ITX main board with DDR3 1333 SODIMM CL9 RAM (2x 2 GB by Transcend) and a 400 watts ATX power supply.

However, the system won't start. The board is powered, the power LED is burning, but that's all: speaker says nothing and the screen remains black (neither by VGA or by HDMI).

Interestingly sometimes the power supply powers up twice when I push the power button: The fans start and the power LED burns for about 4 seconds, then turns off for 2 seconds and restart. Then they run "forever" and nothing more happens.

Any ideas?

*UPDATE*

Meanwhile I'm totally stumped: I tried to start the system with only one RAM bar (for the case that one of them is broken). The system started. Putting the other bar in: it started as well. Putting both back, it won't start (as above).

How can that be?

Comment: If it is new enough, contact Asrock to help trouble shoot.  Could be a faulty integrated CPU or MB going into a fault state in dual channel memory mode.

Comment: It is a used board purchased from an official vendor. I'll contact him. Thanks, @Damon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAM slot B had a defect. A bit more "debugging" showed: Putting any RAM bar in slot A: everything was fine, putting anything in slot B: the board won't start.

I sent the board back, the vendor verified this error and sent me another board working fine.